# Unable to access wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I realized that this question has come up in the past, but I haven't been able to find the solution to my problem.

My wp-admin works fine on my localhost.  However, when I migrate to to my live server, I'm no longer able to access it.  If I do go to mysite/wp-admin, I get a 404 error.

Some things I've tried:

-Disabling all plugins by renaming the folder
-Deleting plugins one by one
-Changing themes
-Editing permissions to 755 for wp-admin folder
-Adding the below to my wp-config file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Note that when I add these lines I get an error that "this page has a redirect loop".

I used the standard wordpress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anybody have any idea what the issue might be?  Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress configuration. It belongs on [wordpress.se]

Comment: Have you tried doing a fresh WP install and export/importing your posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've done the standard troubleshooting tests. Try adding the following lines to your active theme's functions.php file.

```
function flush_my_rules() {

    flush_rewrite_rules();

}

add_action('init','flush_my_rules');
```

Make sure to keep the following lines in your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Then try visiting your homepage first, then your /wp-admin/ page. See if you continue to get a 404. If you do, try visiting the /wp-login.php page, and see if logging in via there continues to return a 404.

Comment: Thanks that allows me to access wp-admin now.  However I can't log in without getting the following error: ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Comment: Oops looks like I just forgot to change the url in the database to my live site... Duh! Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Michael, can you tell me why we have to use the flush_rewrite_rules() in this case?  I've never had this happen to me before.  Thanks

Comment: @DMiller WordPress caches its rewrite rules until something changes in the site that would result in a permalinks flush. The cached rewrite rules will ignore the updated permalink structure, until you flush them.