# wp-admin redirect 404 not found page

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop a site using WordPress and hosts it on cPanel. The site works fine. But after few days later found a problem and the problem is when I try to get access admin panel via https://my-site-url.com/wp-admin it **redirect 404 not found page**.

In database *wp-options* table:
**siteurl** and **home** are ok.

my .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: `.htaccess` file looks ok. Is it possible to reach `https://my-site-url.com/wp-login.php`?

Comment: No, I can't reach wp-login also.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601466/unable-to-access-wp-admin